# How to create df from dictionaries where values from one dict are within another with aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of dictionaries. Both contain some data as well as a start and stop timestamp. The first list contains dictionaries representing observations of sequences of text with a start and stop time and metadata. It looks like this:

```py
list_1 = [
    {
        "words": "hey you",
        "start": 3.27,
        "stop": 4.54,
        "duration": 1.27,
        "consecutive_tally": 0.0,
        "consecutive_time": 1.27,
        "silence_between_previous_utterance": 0,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": ["you"],
    },
    {
        "words": "",
        "start": 7.27,
        "stop": 7.54,
        "duration": 0.271,
        "consecutive_tally": 1.0,
        "consecutive_time": 1.541,
        "silence_between_previous_utterance": 2.73,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": [],
    },
    {
        "words": "",
        "start": 12.91,
        "stop": 13.19,
        "duration": 0.279,
        "consecutive_tally": 0.0,
        "consecutive_time": 0.279,
        "silence_between_previous_utterance": 5.37,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": [],
    },
    {
        "words": "",
        "start": 15.04,
        "stop": 15.13,
        "duration": 0.090,
        "consecutive_tally": 0.0,
        "consecutive_time": 0.090,
        "silence_between_previous_utterance": 1.85,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": [],
    },
    {
        "words": "well how are you?",
        "start": 16.04,
        "stop": 19.13,
        "duration": 3.09,
        "consecutive_tally": 0.0,
        "consecutive_time": 3.09,
        "silence_between_previous_utterance": 0.51,
        "question": 1,
        "pronouns": ["you"],
    },
    {
        "words": "i think its getting late",
        "start": 20.0,
        "stop": 21.1,
        "duration": 1.1,
        "consecutive_tally": 1.0,
        "consecutive_time": 4.19,
        "silence_between_previous_utterance": 0.47,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": ["i"],
    },
]
```

```py
list_2 = [
    {"cat": 99, "start": 0.0, "stop": 7.99},
    {"cat": 14, "start": 8.0, "stop": 9.99},
    {"cat": 10, "start": 10.0, "stop": 12.99},
    {"cat": 99, "start": 13.0, "stop": 15.99},
    {"cat": 10, "start": 16.0, "stop": 23.99},
]
```

I want to aggregate dicts from `list_1` when the `start` and `stop` from `list_1` fall within `start` and `stop` from `list_2`, and add the aggregated data to each dict in `list_2`.

For example, the first 2 dicts in list_1 have their start and stop times falling within the first start and stop time in the first dict from `list_2`. Therefor, I want to aggregate the data in the first 2 `list_1` dicts together in this logic (note I am not using all the items from the dict):

- words = add together ('hey you', ' ')
- consecutive_tally = max (i want the highest value of all consecutive_tally values in the aggregation)
- consecutive_time = sum (add all together)
- silence_between_utterances = sum
- question = sum
- pronouns = add together (['you'], [' '])

If the start/stop range in `list_1` only partially falls between a start/stop range from `list_2`, (ex. `list_1['start'] < list_2['start'] and list_1['stop'] < list_2['stop']`, then I want the data from `list_1` to be added to the latter `list_2` dictionary (where `list_1['stop']` is between `list_2['start']` and `list_2['stop']`.)

If the start/stop range in `list_1` does not fall within the start/stop `list_2` range, then I want to append empty `list_1` dictionary items to the `list_2` dictionary.

Essentially, I want this from the data provided:

```py
list_3 = [
    {
        "cat": 99,
        "start": 0.0,
        "stop": 7.99,
        "words": ["hey you", ""],
        "consecutive_tally": 1.0,
        "consecutive_time": 1.27,
        "silence_between_utterance": 2.73,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": [["you"], [""]],
    },
    {
        "cat": 14,
        "start": 8.0,
        "stop": 9.99,
        "words": [],
        "consecutive_tally": 0,
        "consecutive_time": 0,
        "silence_between_utterance": 0,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": [],
    },
    {
        "cat": 10,
        "start": 10.0,
        "stop": 12.99,
        "words": [],
        "consecutive_tally": 0,
        "consecutive_time": 0,
        "silence_between_utterance": 0,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": [],
    },
    {
        "cat": 99,
        "start": 13.0,
        "stop": 15.99,
        "words": ["", ""],
        "consecutive_tally": 0,
        "consecutive_time": 0.369,
        "silence_between_utterance": 7.22,
        "question": 0,
        "pronouns": ["", ""],
    },
    {
        "cat": 10,
        "start": 16.0,
        "stop": 23.99,
        "words": ["well how are you?", "i think its getting late"],
        "consecutive_tally": 1,
        "consecutive_time": 7.28,
        "silence_between_utterance": 0.98,
        "question": 1,
        "pronouns": [["you"], ["i"]],
    },
]
```

Comment: I submitted an edit to add some missing characters, and try to make the data format more consisten. I hope I understood things correctly :)

Comment: Thanks, your edits are helpful. I would approve if I had the points.

Comment: No worries, it looks like it got approved in the end :)

Comment: shouldn't the second list have one more entry, 6 total like the `len(list1)`?

Comment: @Kenan No, len(list_1) can be anything. It is len(list_2) and len(list_3) that need to be the same. list_1 gets aggregated by the start/stop times into len(list_3).

Comment: No I am talking about `len(list_2)` should have the same as `len(list_1)`, so the comparison is 1 to 1. Unless this is a `n^2` operation which will be more work

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a `n^2` operation. I don't care too much about complexity right now, I just want a working solution and will then optimize.

Comment: Were my guesses and assumptions about the format correct?

Comment: @AMC yes, you were correct, the edits were helpful.